# if(in_array) not executing correctly

Tags: php

I am trying to put together a geodetection for altering slight language variables.

I have the detection working perfectly, but the array check seems to not be working, I need to know if its from a list of countries. If I echo the country then I get the correct name so I know that parts working.

```
//Get User Country

$country_arr = array(
    "Canada" => "ca", 
    "United States" => "us", 
    "United Kingdom" => "uk", 
    "Australia" => "au",
    "South Africa" => "za",
    "Unknow" => "shot"
);

$country=visitor_country();

if (in_array($country, $country_arr)) {
    //include ("languages/" . $lang . ".php");
    //echo $country_arr[$country];
    echo "yes
";
} else {
    //include ("languages/en.php");
    echo "no
";
}

echo $country;
```

Have a functioning sandbox with all the related code working and edible http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/714d5105012f28cada695a6f11dc61516722e6d7

Also not working with a standard 1 dimensional array

```
$count_array = array("South Africa", "Unknow");
```

Comment: i didn't know you can use array as needle or maybe you want to use array_intersect?

Comment: What shows `var_dump($country)` Are you sure you're searching value, not key?

Comment: $country may be empty

Comment: What is wrong... It displays  no since your array does not contains the values you return from the function.So what is the problem.?

Comment: "Unknown" and "Unknow" are not the same. You get "Unknown" in `$country`. Anyway `in_array()` checks against the values of the array and not against its keys. For keys use `array_key_exists()` or `isset($country_arr[$country])`

Comment: That spelling mistake would of made no difference, was testing it live as well and South Africa was spelt correctly.

Comment: @User016 - For you maybe, but for me they are, South Africa is where I am. I also have a vpn setup to test against the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array `array_key_exists` in place of `in_array`

```
//Get User Country

$country = visitor_country();

$country_arr = array(
"Canada" => "ca", 
"United States" => "us", 
"United Kingdom" => "uk", 
"Australia" => "au",
"South Africa" => "za",
"Unknown" => "shot"
);


//$count_array = array("South Africa", "Unknown");

if ( array_key_exists($country, $country_arr) ) {
//include ("languages/" . $lang . ".php");
//echo $country_arr[$country];
echo "yes<br>";
} else {
    //include ("languages/en.php");
    echo "no<br>";
}

echo $country;
```

For in_array function your `$country_arr` array should be like this

```
/* For IN Array */
$country_arr = array(
    "Canada", 
    "United States", 
    "United Kingdom", 
    "Australia",
    "South Africa",
    "Unknown"
);
```

your `$count_array = array("South Africa", "Unknow");` is not working because `$country` returns `Unknown` and you had `Unknow` that's not matching with with the value..

Answer (score 1):

With **in_array** you check values not keys.

```
//Get User Country

$country_arr = array(
    "Canada" => "ca", 
    "United States" => "us", 
    "United Kingdom" => "uk", 
    "Australia" => "au",
    "South Africa" => "za",
    "Unknow" => "shot"
);

$country = 'Canada';

if ( isset($country_arr[$country]) )
{
    echo "yes";
}
else
{
    echo "no"; 
}

echo "\n$country";
```

**BTW**

Keep in mind that PHP even with 'regular' arrays - without keys - have implicit keys so for **in_array** to work you would have to have:

```
$country_arr = array( "Canada", "United States", "United Kingdom" );
```

Above all countries have their keys (but implicit) so countries are values here. On your original code countries are keys.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo - `Unknow` / `Unknown`, also, you're not searching against keys with `in_array()`, you need to use `array_key_exists()` or `array_flip($country_arr)`

Answer (score -1):

Your GeoIP service returns `countryName` and `countryCode` fields. Just use `countryCode` instead of `countryName` and your code will work:

```
if($ip_data && $ip_data->geoplugin_countryCode != null)
    {
        $result = $ip_data->geoplugin_countryCode;
    }
```